# Processing R2RML mappings in Virtuoso

Tags: rdf, protege, virtuoso, triplestore, r2rml

I have a R2RML mapping file generated with the OnTop Protege Plugin. My purpose is to use these mappings in order to replicate my relational Database in RDF format. Then I want to upload this RDF file into an existing Virtuoso Server.

I am aware that Virtuoso offers R2RML Support (https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtR2RML). However, first of all I am not able to install the RDB2RDF_VAD package since I cannot find it.

I have seen the tutorial (https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtConductorR2RMLImportNorthwind) to generate RDF graphs from an R2RML mapping file. However, I would like to know if there is any equivalent way of doing this in a more 'programatical' way because I want to automatize this process for several databases.

Answer (score 1):

The "R2RML Processor Module" (`rdb2rdf_dav.vad`) is available through [the main Virtuoso downloads area for Commercial Edition](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/), or more directly for [Commercial](http://opldownload.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-packages/) or [Open Source](http://opldownload.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-vos-packages/).  *Be sure to get the VAD built for your Virtuoso server version (or the nearest-lower)!*

VAD packages are most easily installed with the [Virtuoso Conductor](http://virtuoso-host-fqdn:8890/conductor/), in the **System Admin** -> **Packages** tab, but you can also [use iSQL commands](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/vaddistr/).

I believe ["Generate Linked Data Views via R2RML from iSQL"](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtGenerateR2RMLLinkedDataView) covers the programmatic solution you are wishing for, as it starts --

> Using Virtuoso you can programmatically generate Linked Data Views atop Relational Data Sources, using R2RML via the built-in `R2RML_GENERATE_LINKED_VIEW` function. In order to use this function, you need to have the `rdb2rdf_dav.vad` package installed.

*(All documentation to which you or I have linked will be updated soon, to reflect the updated download locations I linked above.)*

Comment: I was able to install the R2RML Processor Module, following the steps of this tutorial: https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtEC2AMIDBpediaInstall#DBpedia VAD Application Package

Comment: @Havor - I've edited my answer to include more details (and the link you provided should have been [https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtEC2AMIDBpediaInstall#DBpedia%20VAD%20Application%20Package](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtEC2AMIDBpediaInstall#DBpedia%20VAD%20Application%20Package)).